# Inherit of svn:ignore properties in a subfolder doesn't work

Tags: svn, inheritance, ignore

Inherit of svn:ignore properties in a subfolder doesn't work.

As show in [this screenshot](http://screenshot.ru/0e5889132f63163fb72d21aeba6de8d7.png),
TortoiseSVN shows the following SVN properties for the folder `ScenesAnim/z.SampleFolderStructure.z/Scenes`, as well as showing that the file `.Test.png` is not being svn-ignored as one would expect.

```
| Property   | Value                                                                | Inherited From |
| svn:ignore | -R " *Feedback *.png *.zip *.rar *.wmv *.avi *.tga BackSceneSource " | ScenesAnim/z.SampleFolderStructure.z |
```

Why is it so? Is there an option to not to mark "Apply property recursively" flag under a properties window every time a create a subfolder to make it ignore the list again and again?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of your `svn:ignore` property looks faulty. The `-R` part is the parameter telling the Subversion CLI executable to apply a command recursively, it does not belong in there. The double-quotes don't belong in there as well. Get rid of both and just <strike>put</strike> keep each of the exclusion masks in a single line, and you should be fine.

**Clarification:** An exclusion mask is a term like `*.tga`. In your screenshot above, *each of your exclusion masks already is on a single line*. I just wanted to emphasize that this is in fact needed, because if all exclusion masks were combined on a single line, it would not work. Just get rid of the first two lines (the ones with `-R` and double quote) and the last one (double quote again).

*Concerning your second question:*

> Is there an option to not to mark "Apply property recursively" flag under a properties window every time a create a subfolder to make it ignore the list again and again?

If you are applying a property recursively it means that SVN will, from the current folder (let's call it `CURRENT`), iterate through all subfolders and *explicitly set that property on every subfolder*. Now, if you add a folder somewhere beneath the `CURRENT` folder, this new folder *will not* automatically inherit the property you recursively defined before. It's an unfortunate shortcoming of the `svn:ignore` property.

*Sidenote:* Subversion 1.8 introduced "real" inheritable ignores with a [reserved property called `svn:global-ignores`](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config), which supposedly does exactly what you want (use the inherited ignore), but I don't have experience with that yet.

Comment: Single line? I noticed that Tortoise puts the exlusions each in different line. I'm not sure, but I think I tried to write them all in single line both with (-R, and --recursive). Every my attempt made me to mark the "Apply property recursive" every time when I created a new folder.

Thanks for reply! I'm a graphic designer/animator, not a programmer. So, be patient if I get you wrong.

Comment: subfolders inherit works with "svn:global-ignores" property! Thanks for solution!